# mytop install and term::readkey

Tags: perl, rpm

```
[host]# rpm -Uvh mytop-1.6-4.el5.noarch.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl(Term::ReadKey) >= 2.1 is needed by mytop-1.6-4.el5.noarch
[host]# ./perlmodver Term::ReadKey
Term::ReadKey: 2.30
```

Why is rpm failing to install mytop when this perl module version is greater than 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you installed Term::ReadKey from CPAN, and those files are not registered in the RPM database.

Remedy, install the perl-TermReadKey package:

```
# yum install perl-TermReadKey
```

Let the package manager tools resolve the RPM dependencies for you: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/